# C# foreach on children of an abstract

Tags: c#, list, foreach, abstract, children

I'm new to C# and my question is:
I have a class named

> AbstractItem

and there are 3 children to this class.
My code is:

```
private void AddChecker(List<AbstractItem> getByChosenField)
    {
        if (getByChosenField == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Entry list is currently empty.");
        }
        else {
            LibraryList.Items.Clear(); // simply if there are no results then list remains empty.
            if (getByChosenField.OfType<Reading>().Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Reading item in getByChosenField)
                {
                    LibraryList.Items.Add(
                        new MyItems
                        {
                            ItemName = item.ItemName,
                            CopyNumber = int.Parse(item.CopyNumber.ToString()),
                            Guid = int.Parse(item.Guid.ToString()),
                            TimePrinted = item.Time,
                            BestSeller = item.BestSeller,
                            Category = item.BookCategory.ToString(),
                            SubCategory = item.ReadingBookSubCategory.ToString()
                        });
                }
            }
            if (getByChosenField.OfType<Cooking>().Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Cooking item in getByChosenField)
                {
                    LibraryList.Items.Add(
                        new MyItems
                        {
                            ItemName = item.ItemName,
                            CopyNumber = int.Parse(item.CopyNumber.ToString()),
                            Guid = int.Parse(item.Guid.ToString()),
                            TimePrinted = item.Time,
                            BestSeller = item.BestSeller,
                            Category = item.BookCategory.ToString(),
                            SubCategory = item.CookingBookSubCategory.ToString()
                        });
                }
            }
            if (getByChosenField.OfType<Science>().Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Science item in getByChosenField)
                {
                    LibraryList.Items.Add(
                        new MyItems
                        {
                            ItemName = item.ItemName,
                            CopyNumber = int.Parse(item.CopyNumber.ToString()),
                            Guid = int.Parse(item.Guid.ToString()),
                            TimePrinted = item.Time,
                            BestSeller = item.BestSeller,
                            Category = item.BookCategory.ToString(),
                            SubCategory = item.ScienceBookSubCategory.ToString()
                        });
                }
            }
            if (getByChosenField.OfType<Journal>().Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Journal item in getByChosenField)
                {
                    LibraryList.Items.Add(
                        new MyItems
                        {
                            ItemName = item.ItemName,
                            CopyNumber = int.Parse(item.CopyNumber.ToString()),
                            Guid = int.Parse(item.Guid.ToString()),
                            TimePrinted = item.Time,
                            Category = "Journal",
                            SubCategory = item.JournalCategory.ToString()
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is getting all of the values inside this List that matches getByChosenField.
Now, GetByChosenField in my case is a **BookName** that returns all of the books in the list that are currently with the **BookName** name. 

The code that does the searching is indeed working.
The problem is, if I have a book name **Harry Potter** inside **Cooking** and also **Reading** and\or **Science**, I get an error:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'CommonBookLib.Cooking' to type 'CommonBookLib.Reading'.

This error occures only when I have at least 2 book names of other Categories (Reading\Cooking\Science\Journal).
In case of one book name, everything is fine.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a reason the abstract parent does not define a simple `SubCategory` member that all the children can inherit. It would make the code a lot simpler, you would only need one `foreach` instead of 3 and just have the foreach be `foreach(AbstractItem item in getByChosenField)`

Comment: Also, doing 4 `foreach` could be quite slow with a large list. You may want to consider doing a single `foreach(var abstractItem in getByChosenField)` then inside the `foreach` do `var scienceItem = abstractItem as Science;`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What you said actually works better now. Before I could potentially get suddnely another category and now with the var bla = item as Type it works fantastic. What is it exactly? What's the purpose? Any source to understand this?

Comment: See from the MSDN [How to: Safely Cast by Using as and is Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx), you likely want to do the "UseAsOperator` function example. Basically `as` will check if the type  on the right is a able to be casted, if it can it returns the cast type, if it can't it returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there.

You know how to filter the list to those items of a specific subtype.

Just apply that filter to the `IEnumerable` you are iterating over

```
        if (getByChosenField.OfType<Reading>().Any()) // Faster than Count() > 0
        {
            foreach (Reading item in getByChosenField.OfType<Reading>())
            {
                LibraryList.Items.Add(
                    new MyItems
                    {
                        ItemName = item.ItemName,
                        CopyNumber = int.Parse(item.CopyNumber.ToString()),
                        Guid = int.Parse(item.Guid.ToString()),
                        TimePrinted = item.Time,
                        BestSeller = item.BestSeller,
                        Category = item.BookCategory.ToString(),
                        SubCategory = item.ReadingBookSubCategory.ToString()
                    });
            }
        }
```

Of course, once we do this, the `if` clause becomes superfluous. If there are no items of the matching type, it will simply skip over the loop.

```
 foreach (Reading item in getByChosenField.OfType<Reading>())
 {
      // Add the Reading item
 }
 foreach(Cooking item in getByChosenField.OfType<Cooking>()) 
 {
    //Add the Cooking item
 }
 foreach(Science item in getByChosenField.OfType<Science>())
 {
    // Add the science item
 }
```

Comment: For some reason I still get this: `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'CommonBookLib.Cooking' to type 'CommonBookLib.Reading'.`. I dont get it.. if I make sure to filter it and it works for one value than why more than one value gets an exception? it seems that for one value, one of the foreach conditions happens, but for two or more it collides.

Comment: Damn! Just now I saw the second condition you made. Thx, thats the answer.